# Java Swing Resource for jRuby developer?

Tags: java, swing, jruby

I'm looking to develop GUI apps using jRuby but, am not sure which would be a good Swing book or tutorial to start with in my studies.

Comment: a general swing book or specifically swing with jruby?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to build a desktop application in ruby or in java? (jruby is ruby running on java so swing via ruby is possible but not the easiest way)

For Java I recommend to start with [suns tutorial here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/), [netbeans matisse there](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/matisse.html) or [javafx](http://javafx.com/samples/). Or even take a look into the groovy desktop framework called [griffon](http://griffon.codehaus.org/).

For ruby I know

- http://swiby.codehaus.org/
- http://shoes.heroku.com/

Answer (score 0):

A direct pointer to what you require .... http://wiki.netbeans.org/SwingJRuby

It considers that you are using NetBeans ... even if you are not it could be useful